# Time-Series Graph for weighted frequencies of character variable in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

Let's assume this dataset:

```
answer <- c("a", "b", "b", NA, "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", NA, "a", "b")
weights <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 1.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.5, 0.9, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13)
year <- c(2001, 2005, 2010)
data <- cbind(answer,weights,year)
```

I want to have a time-series plot which shows the weighted frequencies of the possible answers (`a` and `b`). `NA` should be omitted. 
 Any idea how to achieve that? 
Thanks in advance!

If I should rewrite my question, please let me know. I am new in the community...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! You can manage it with `dplyr` to tidy the data, and `ggplot2` to plot them, all wrapped in a `dplyr` chain with the `magrittr` `%>%` (pipe) operator. Read about all those packages, they are very useful.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  # remove NAS
  filter(!is.na(answer)) %>%    
  # group by  
  group_by(answer, year) %>%
  # add a column made by the sums per year/answer: you can use other functions
  summarise(weights = sum(weights)) %>%
  # now the plot
  ggplot(.,aes(x = sprintf("%.0f", year),   # sprintf to remove decimal to years
               y = weights,                 
              colour = answer,
              group = answer)) + 
 geom_line()  +                             # add lines
 labs(                                      # rename x axis
       x = "summed weights"
      )
```

[image]

**P.S.**

I used `data.frame` instead of `cbind` for the data, something like:

```
data <- data.frame(answer,weights,year)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!